# How can i make my Bash start where i worked last?

Tags: macos, bash

Can I somehow config my bash to be auto located in the last path I worked when I open it again ?
E.g. yesterday I worked in my git repository (local machine) so I had to cd myself to "/Applications/.../git/" which is quite long.

After work I quit my bash.

Today I want to start right there when I open the bash without having to cd again. Is this somehow possible?

regards.

Comment: One approach would be to alias `cd` to both perform `cd` and write the new path to a file, then `cd < lastPathFile` as part of your bash.rc (is that what it's called... been so long :-) script.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I can come up with for now is kinda hacky... When a login shell terminates, it runs `~/.bash_logout`. Adding `pwd > ~/.lastdir` to that file, you could then do `cd $(cat ~/.lastdir)` in your `.bashrc`. The hackyness is that you'd have to run all your terminals as login shells.

Comment: You could also `trap … EXIT`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your ~/.bashrc file

```
trap 'pwd > $HOME/.lastdir; exit' 0
if [ -f "$HOME/.lastdir" ]; then
    cd `cat $HOME/.lastdir`
fi
```

Comment: +1 for this! but for me worked at the 3rd login, can you tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `screen`. This is a very useful tool for remote management, because it includes features of a bash screen, such as multiple tabs. The most notable feature is the session management: It's possible to return to one of your previous session, which also includes the screen's output and the last entered commands (of all virtual tabs).

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add the command `cd path_to_folder` in the .bashrc file in users' home directory.